# Chain of async calls where the last call compares something from the first

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I need to complete a number of fetch requests where each relies on the successful completion of the last. For the final request, I need to compare a value from the first request.

Here's what I've got, and it appears to work, but I'm not sure if I have this 100% correct.

```
const getData = async ( id ) => {
    return await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
    .then( json => json.json() )
    .then( res => res )
}

const res_1 = await getData( 1 ).then( res => res )
const res_2 = await getData( res_1.id + 1 ).then( res => res )
const res_3 = await getData( res_2.id + 1 ).then( res => res )
const res_4 = await getData( res_3.id + 1 ).then( res => res )

console.log(`RES_1: \n${JSON.stringify(res_1)}`)
console.log(`RES_2: \n${JSON.stringify(res_2)}`)
console.log(`RES_3: \n${JSON.stringify(res_3)}`)
console.log(`RES_4: \n${JSON.stringify(res_4)}`)

if ( res_1.id !== res_4.id ) {
    console.log("Id's don't match")
} else {
    console.log("Id's match")
}
```

You may ignore the logging, it's simply to visualize what's happening.

Comment: yes this is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need additional `.then( res => res )` as it just returning the same object back again. Also, as you are using async/await you can remove `.then(...)` and just `await` on the result of the promise. Also, we can use `await` inside an `async` function only, so you can put all your logic inside an async function `fn` like:

```js
const getData = async(id) => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
  return res.json();
}

async function fn() {
  const res_1 = await getData(1)
  const res_2 = await getData(res_1.id + 1)
  const res_3 = await getData(res_2.id + 1)
  const res_4 = await getData(res_3.id + 1)
  
  console.log('res_1.id: ', res_1.id);
  console.log('res_4.id: ', res_4.id);
  
  if (res_1.id !== res_4.id) {
    console.log("Id's don't match")
  } else {
    console.log("Id's match")
  }
}

fn();
```

Or, you can also use immediately-invoked async function expressions for this purpose like:

```js
const getData = async(id) => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
  return res.json();
}

(async function() {
  const res_1 = await getData(1)
  const res_2 = await getData(res_1.id + 1)
  const res_3 = await getData(res_2.id + 1)
  const res_4 = await getData(res_3.id + 1)

  console.log('res_1.id: ', res_1.id);
  console.log('res_4.id: ', res_4.id);

  if (res_1.id !== res_4.id) {
    console.log("Id's don't match")
  } else {
    console.log("Id's match")
  }
}());
```